# Taking out just one value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [picture] => 5a55ed8d8a5c8910913.jpeg 
                       [id] => 1284 
                       [price_range] => Rs 12000 - 9000 
                       [name] => Brown Beauty Office Chair ) 
        [1] => Array ( [picture] => 5a55eefeb9a8e255836.jpeg 
                       [id] => 1285 
                       [price_range] => Rs 8989 - 7000 
                       [name] => Chang Series Office Chair (Grey) 
                     ) 
      )
```

Now I am fetching the value of id on clicking a remove button, the value I fetch is `1284`.

I want to take out just `[id]=> 1284` from the above array and then display it using a foreach loop. How I can delete just the `[id]=> 1284` without disturbing the other id values and other element.

In the above array I would like to delete one particular id value say just the [id]=> 1284 and keep all other elements intact and as it is.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: can you send your code by jsfiddle?

Comment: bit unclear what you're asking

Comment: How about you write a loop? Other than that, `array_filter` or `array_reduce` may come in handy for that, too. Where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_search` and `array_column`, to find by `id` and remove by `unset` method,

```
<?php
$array =  [
  ["id"=>123,"desc"=>"test1"],
  ["id"=>456,"desc"=>"test2"],
  ["id"=>789,"desc"=>"test3"],
];
$id = 456;
$index = array_search($id, array_column($array, 'id'));
unset($array[$index]);
print_r($array);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/933297)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [desc] => test1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 789
            [desc] => test3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how to achieve it using foreach, I came up with this.

```
    $array = Array (Array ( 'picture' => '5a55ed8d8a5c8910913.jpeg','id' => 1284,'price_range' => 'Rs 12000 - 9000', 'name' => 'Brown Beauty Office Chair'),
        Array ( 'picture' => '5a55eefeb9a8e255836.jpeg','id' => 1285,'price_range' => 'Rs 8989 - 7000','name' => 'Chang Series Office Chair (Grey)')
        );
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        $id = $array[$key]['id'];
        if($id === 1284){            
            unset($array[$key]['id']);
        }

    }
    print_r($array)
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this too:

```
<?php 
$element_to_remove = 1284;
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $this_arr){

    $index = array_search($element_to_remove, $this_arr);
    //unset($this_arr[$index]); this formate does not remove element from array

    //but below works fine
    if(isset($array[$i][$index])){
        unset($array[$i][$index]);  
    }
}
print_r($array);
?>
```